# Integrating objects with IRKernel

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

Similar to how you can write `_repr_html_` for a repr on an object in Python, I'd like to be able to decorate objects in R for inspection with the IRKernel (while not interfering with regular R usage of the library). How should I be writing R to make it nicer for Jupyter users?

Comment: for data.frame, you might want to consider using `print(xtable::xtable(data.frame(A=1:2, B=3:4)), "html")`.

Comment: @chinsoon12 - I'm looking to create a representation of the SparkContext from Sparklyr or SparkR, as well as know how to advise others to provide custom outputs

Answer (score 2):

The main kind of classes in R are [S3 classes](http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s3Classes.html), and these are what IRKernel's [repr](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr) library knows about.

Methods on S3 classes are more like generic functions. *repr* declares a number of generic functions like `repr_html`. If you define a class called `frob`, you can provide a function called `repr_html.frob` which returns the HTML to represent your object. All the magic for method lookup is based on the name, as far as I know, so you can define the `repr_html.frob` function as normal - it doesn't matter what package it's in, so long as the user loads the package before the kernel tries to display your object.

The generic functions repr declares are:

- repr_text
- repr_html
- repr_markdown
- repr_latex
- repr_json
- repr_javascript
- repr_pdf
- repr_png
- repr_jpg
- repr_svg

As in Python, you can define as many or as few of these as makes sense. See [the repr code](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/tree/master/R) for some examples.

Comment: Do you have an example notebook that does this for a custom class?

Comment: Not that I know of, no. Feel free to open an issue (or a PR ;-) on IRkernel for it.

Comment: Yeah I got fairly stuck so I won't be able to make a PR just yet. :)

Comment: You're welcome to open an issue - Philipp might have more time to provide an example.